# Не могу запустить npm run dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, webpack

При запуске npm run dev выдает ошибку внизу

```
PS C:\Users\ArmanTu\Desktop\new-reddit> npm run dev
Debugger attached.

> new-reddit@1.0.0 dev
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./bin/dev.js

Debugger attached.
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
C:\Users\ArmanTu\Desktop\new-reddit\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:158
    throw new _ValidationError.default(errors, schema, configuration);
    ^

ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Middleware has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'watchOptions'. These properties are valid:
   object { mimeTypes?, mimeTypeDefault?, writeToDisk?, methods?, headers?, publicPath?, stats?, serverSideRender?, outputFileSystem?, index?, modifyResponseData? }
    at validate (C:\Users\ArmanTu\Desktop\new-reddit\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:158:11)
    at wdm (C:\Users\ArmanTu\Desktop\new-reddit\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\dist\index.js:171:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ArmanTu\Desktop\new-reddit\bin\dev.js:13:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errors: [
    {
      instancePath: '',
      schemaPath: '#/additionalProperties',
      keyword: 'additionalProperties',
      params: { additionalProperty: 'watchOptions' },
      message: 'must NOT have additional properties',
      schema: false,
      parentSchema: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          mimeTypes: {
            description: 'Allows a user to register custom mime types or extension mappings.',
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#mimetypes',
            type: 'object'
          },
          mimeTypeDefault: {
            description: "Allows a user to register a default mime type when we can't determine the content type.",
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#mimetypedefault',
            type: 'string'
          },
          writeToDisk: {
            description: 'Allows to write generated files on disk.',
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#writetodisk',
            anyOf: [Array]
          },
          methods: {
            description: 'Allows to pass the list of HTTP request methods accepted by the middleware.',
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#methods',
            type: 'array',
            items: [Object]
          },
          headers: {
            anyOf: [Array],
            description: 'Allows to pass custom HTTP headers on each request',
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#headers'
          },
          publicPath: {
            description: 'The `publicPath` specifies the public URL address of the output files when referenced in a browser.',
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#publicpath',
            anyOf: [Array]
          },
          stats: {
            description: 'Stats options object or preset name.',
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#stats',
            anyOf: [Array]
          },
          serverSideRender: {
            description: 'Instructs the module to enable or disable the server-side rendering mode.',
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#serversiderender',
            type: 'boolean'
          },
          outputFileSystem: {
            description: 'Set the default file system which will be used by webpack as primary destination of generated files.',
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#outputfilesystem',
            type: 'object'
          },
          index: {
            description: 'Allows to serve an index of the directory.',
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#index',
            anyOf: [Array]
          },
          modifyResponseData: {
            description: 'Allows to set up a callback to change the response data.',
            link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#modifyresponsedata',
            instanceof: 'Function'
          }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      },
      data: {
        publicPath: '/static',
        serverSideRender: true,
        noInfo: true,
        watchOptions: { ignore: '**/dist' },
        writeToDisk: true,
        stats: 'errors-only'
      },
      children: [
        {
          instancePath: '',
          schemaPath: '#/additionalProperties',
          keyword: 'additionalProperties',
          params: { additionalProperty: 'noInfo' },
          message: 'must NOT have additional properties',
          schema: false,
          parentSchema: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: [Object],
            additionalProperties: false
          },
          data: {
            publicPath: '/static',
            serverSideRender: true,
            noInfo: true,
            watchOptions: [Object],
            writeToDisk: true,
            stats: 'errors-only'
          },
          children: undefined
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  schema: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      mimeTypes: {
        description: 'Allows a user to register custom mime types or extension mappings.',
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#mimetypes',
        type: 'object'
      },
      mimeTypeDefault: {
        description: "Allows a user to register a default mime type when we can't determine the content type.",
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#mimetypedefault',
        type: 'string'
      },
      writeToDisk: {
        description: 'Allows to write generated files on disk.',
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#writetodisk',
        anyOf: [ { type: 'boolean' }, { instanceof: 'Function' } ]
      },
      methods: {
        description: 'Allows to pass the list of HTTP request methods accepted by the middleware.',
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#methods',
        type: 'array',
        items: { type: 'string', minLength: 1 }
      },
      headers: {
        anyOf: [
          { type: 'array', items: [Object], minItems: 1 },
          { type: 'object' },
          { instanceof: 'Function' }
        ],
        description: 'Allows to pass custom HTTP headers on each request',
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#headers'
      },
      publicPath: {
        description: 'The `publicPath` specifies the public URL address of the output files when referenced in a browser.',
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#publicpath',
        anyOf: [
          { enum: [Array] },
          { type: 'string' },
          { instanceof: 'Function' }
        ]
      },
      stats: {
        description: 'Stats options object or preset name.',
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#stats',
        anyOf: [
          { enum: [Array] },
          { type: 'boolean' },
          { type: 'object', additionalProperties: true }
        ]
      },
      serverSideRender: {
        description: 'Instructs the module to enable or disable the server-side rendering mode.',
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#serversiderender',
        type: 'boolean'
      },
      outputFileSystem: {
        description: 'Set the default file system which will be used by webpack as primary destination of generated files.',
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#outputfilesystem',
        type: 'object'
      },
      index: {
        description: 'Allows to serve an index of the directory.',
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#index',
        anyOf: [ { type: 'boolean' }, { type: 'string', minLength: 1 } ]
      },
      modifyResponseData: {
        description: 'Allows to set up a callback to change the response data.',
        link: 'https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#modifyresponsedata',
        instanceof: 'Function'
      }
    },
    additionalProperties: false
  },
  headerName: 'Dev Middleware',
  baseDataPath: 'options',
  postFormatter: null
}
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Содержание package.json

```
{
  "name": "new-reddit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./bin/dev.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^6.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

содержание bin/dev.js

```
const [webpackClientConfig, webpacServerConfig] = require ('../webpack.config')
const nodemon = require('nodemon');
const path = require('path');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const express = require('express');


const hmrServer = express();
const clientCompiler = webpack(webpackClientConfig);

hmrServer.use(webpackDevMiddleware(clientCompiler, {
    publicPath: webpackClientConfig.output.publicPath,
    serverSideRender: true,
    noInfo: true,
    watchOptions: {
        ignore: /dist/,
    },
    writeToDisk: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',

}));

hmrServer.use(webpackHotMiddleware(clientCompiler, {
    path: '/static/__webpack_hmr',
}))

hmrServer.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('HMR server successfully started')
});

const compiler = webpack(webpacServerConfig);

compiler.run((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Compilation failed: ', err);
    }


compiler.watch({}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Compilation failed: ', err);
    }
    console.log('Compilation was successfully');
});


    nodemon({
        script: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/server/server.js'),
        watch: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/server'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/client'),
        ]
    })
});
```

Comment: Ищите ошибку в коде, где у вас вызывается валидация. Файлы выше вроде как не причастны к этому